# Posting swf to newsfeed ("Feed Gaming")

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, feed

I'm having trouble posting a playable swf to the newsfeed a la "Feed Gaming".  The open graph object in my_og.php (code below) looks fine in the facebook debugger and recognizes that it is a video embed.  But when I post to the feed using the javascript api and feed dialog (code below), it doesn't recognize that it should be able to be clicked on and load the swf to play and just displays the static image.

js api call:

```
var obj = {method: 'feed', link: 'http://example.com/my_og.php'};
FB.ui(obj, function(response) {});
```

my_og.php :

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb">    

<meta property="fb:app_id"       content="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<meta property="og:type"         content="game" />
<meta property="og:url"          content="http://example.com/my_og.php" />
<meta property="og:title"        content="title" />
<meta property="og:description"  content="desc" />
<meta property="og:image"        content="http://example.com/test.png" />
<meta property="og:video"        content="http://example.com/test.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:width"  content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:type"   content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

</head>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working without any changes.  Must have been a fix on Facebook's side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a "source" property that points to your swf file (instead of "video" in your code) and a "picture" property that points to your icon (instead of "image").  That is what I did and it started working